# Reclaim space from Core Data SQLite store with NSPersistentContainer?

Tags: sqlite, caching, core-data, vacuum

My app implements a web cache using Core Data with an SQLite store (a bit like NSURLCache but with more control over what is cached and when it can be purged from the cache).  I can purge old data from the cache when it gets too big, but of course this does not actually reduce the amount of storage space used in the file system.

I know that NSPersistentStoreCoordinator can be passed the [NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/store_options?language=objc) option to do an SQLite vacuum on opening the store, and I thought this might be a good way to reduce the file size (even if I have to temporarily close and re-open the store).

However, I am managing the Core Data stack through an NSPersistentContainer.  Is there any way to do an Apple-approved SQLite vacuum with an NSPersistentContainer?

Or do I have to establish the Core Data stack manually to do this?

Or otherwise how else should I reclaim SQLite storage space when using an NSPersistentConainer?

**CORRECTION**:

I was partly wrong about the space not being reclaimed automatically.  Even without setting `NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption`, the disk space is being reclaimed automatically - sometimes.  I'm not sure how this is working.  It doesn't happen immediately and it doesn't happen every time I save the context, but when it does happen, it is very quickly after deleting managed objects from the context and saving the context.

If I do a series of delete/save commands, the storage space is not freed in between them.  But if I check again shortly afterwards, the space has been reclaimed (sometimes).

Perhaps Core Data is using the 'auto_vacuum' SQLite pragma by default?  Although if I log the sqlite pragmas, it just prints an empty dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work like this; I've never done it myself:

Create an [NSPersistentStoreDescription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstoredescription) and set the options to include the [`NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nssqlitemanualvacuumoption).  Assign this description to the the `NSPersistentContainer`'s [`persistentStoreDescriptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer/1640577-persistentstoredescriptions) property before loading the store.

Comment: Thanks... I don't know why I couldn't see this myself.  Also it's worth noting that I was wrong about the space not being reclaimed automatically.  Even without setting `NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption `, the disk space is being reclaimed automatically.  I'm not sure how this is working.